# When we say the odd degree polynomial has odd number of real roots, is there any condition on the coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, quadratics, cubics

I read that if the degree of a polynomial equation is odd then the number of real roots will also be odd.

I took the example of a cubic equation. If it has imaginary roots then that will occur in pair. Thus, the cubic will have at least one real root.

But imaginary roots occur in pair when the coefficients are real.

Also, if I look at the graphs of cubic equations, I see that it crosses x-axis at least once, thus it has atleast one real root.

But is it possible that the coefficients are imaginary and all three roots are imaginary?

Comment: What about $$(X-i)(X-2i)(X-3i)?$$

Comment: @P.Lawrence thankyou

Comment: To be clear, when speaking carefully, we *don't* say that an odd degree polynomial will have an odd number of real roots. What we say is that an odd degree *real* polynomial (i.e., one with real numbers for coefficients) has an odd number of real roots. When you see the statement without the "real" requirement, it is because that part is implied by the context in which the statement is made. If we are discussing real functions of a real variable, then we do not say "real" every last single time, because it should be understood.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see your point, thanks.